# Animated gif alternative using jQuery to animate an image sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I put together this very simple jQuery code to animate a sequence of images. It works perfectly. you can [view it here](https://codepen.io/wilhelm-coq/pen/ExaMqNe).

But now I am trying to update the code so it could work on multiple image sequences at once as long as it has its own class that is referenced in the jQuery code. So I updated it - view below. Unfortunately my updates are not working. Can you guys help me resolve this issue? Thank you in advance!

```js
let aniOne = $(".animation.first img");
let aniTwo = $(".animation.second img");
let currentImg = 0;

function changeImg(allImg){
  $(allImg[currentImg]).fadeOut(0, function(){
    
  if(currentImg == allImg.length -1){
    currentImg = 0;
  }else {
    currentImg++;
  }
    $(allImg[currentImg]).fadeIn(0)});
  
  
}

setInterval(changeImg(aniOne), 0050);

setInterval(changeImg(aniTwo), 0050);
```

```css
.animation {
  width: 30%;
}

.animation img {
  display: none;
}

.animation img:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animation first">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/t57meexkb/horse_1.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/i86apnasr/horse_2.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6kc8v3lnv/horse_3.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/w4ej1j71n/horse_4.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/ddclrdch7/horse_5.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/nbxkdulwr/horse_6.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/phrv8cpd7/horse_7.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/n1un88wob/horse_8.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/9yz0oz6gb/horse_9.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6gn0sl5kb/horse_10.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/vnxwsu8ob/horse_11.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/bhuetyd0r/horse_12.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/imc82zka3/horse_13.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/auvi4fg4r/horse_14.png">
</div>

<div class="animation second">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5QGZklx.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5QGZklx.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/i1oLaES.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you attach the working code as well so that we can compare them?

Comment: Hey @Laif Thank you for your response, Its in the codepen link in the first paragraph of the post. Are you unable to view it?

Comment: Ah, I am, my bad.

Comment: The working code uses `setInterval(changeImg, 50)` which will work fine. The problem with your current attempt is `setInterval(changeImg(aniOne), 50)` which evaluates to a call to `changeImg(aniOne)`, then a call to `setInterval(undefined, 50)` (since changeImg doesn't return anything). If you want this to work, you need to make `changeImg` into a function that returns a function.

Comment: that gets stuff moving but causes other strange issues @ChrisG. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the two sharing the same image count variable

Comment: Alternate solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fwu60qxt/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your response. This works really well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris G stated above:

> The working code uses `setInterval(changeImg, 50)` which will work fine. The problem with your current attempt is `setInterval(changeImg(aniOne), 50)` which evaluates to a call to `changeImg(aniOne)`, then a call to `setInterval(undefined, 50)` (since `changeImg` doesn't return anything). If you want this to work, you need to make `changeImg` into a function that returns a function. – Chris G

After we add these problems, we then have the issue of both animations sharing the `currentImg` variable, so instead I made two different variables and passed them along with the images. You can handle this many different ways.

```js
let aniOne = $(".animation.first img");
let aniTwo = $(".animation.second img");
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 0;

function changeImg(allImg, num){
  function main(){
    $(allImg[num]).fadeOut(0, function(){

    if(num == allImg.length -1){
      num = 0;
    }else {
      num++;
    }
      $(allImg[num]).fadeIn(0)});
  }
  return main;
}

setInterval(changeImg(aniOne, num1), 0050);

setInterval(changeImg(aniTwo, num2), 0050);
```

```css
.animation {
  width: 30%;
}

.animation img {
  display: none;
}

.animation img:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animation first">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/t57meexkb/horse_1.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/i86apnasr/horse_2.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6kc8v3lnv/horse_3.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/w4ej1j71n/horse_4.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/ddclrdch7/horse_5.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/nbxkdulwr/horse_6.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/phrv8cpd7/horse_7.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/n1un88wob/horse_8.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/9yz0oz6gb/horse_9.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6gn0sl5kb/horse_10.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/vnxwsu8ob/horse_11.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/bhuetyd0r/horse_12.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/imc82zka3/horse_13.png">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/auvi4fg4r/horse_14.png">
</div>

<div class="animation second">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5QGZklx.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5QGZklx.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/i1oLaES.png">
</div>
```

Comment: @Will When an answer addresses your question, make sure to mark it as "answered"

Comment: @Will Yep, you got it

Comment: hey there, thanks for adding this answer. However this is jerking in FF, basically in the first loop of allImg is from display none to block is flashing. Any Ideas ?

Comment: This answer is 2 years old by now, and I really cannot tell without more specific detail. I would suggest making a new question with your specific issue. I will check it out.